# AWS Systems Manager unable to execute command on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I created an EC2 instance in a private subnet with a VPC endpoint, with hope of connecting to it through Systems Manager. In the AWS Systems Manager, the instance shows online and running.

However, when I try to execute a command on the instance, it just hangs with a Status of "Pending - Delayed" (I tried very simple Linux commands such as 'pwd')

Here's my CloudFormation template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Creates an EC2 instance for processing raw data.

################################################################################
#
# PARAMETERS
#
################################################################################

Parameters:

  Prefix:
    Description: This prefix will be prepended to all resource names.
    Type: String
    Default: my-company

  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that will be prefixed to resource names
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - stg
      - uat
      - prod
    Default: prod

  VpcStackName:
    Description: The VPC stack name
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-stack

  EC2InstanceType:
    Description: The pipeline EC2 instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro

  EC2ImageId:
    Description: An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) ID
    Type: String
    Default: ami-0e731c8a588258d0d

  SSHKeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Description: SSH Key for the EC2 Instance
    ConstraintDescription: Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair
    Default: pipeline-key

################################################################################
#
# RESOURCES
#
################################################################################

Resources:

  ##############################################################################
  #
  # SECURITY
  #
  ##############################################################################

  PipelineEc2Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref Prefix, !Ref EnvironmentName, 'ec2-ssm-role', !Select [ 7, !Split [ '-', !Ref AWS::StackId ] ] ] ]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore

  PipelineEc2InstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: PipelineEc2Role

  SsmSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref Prefix, !Ref EnvironmentName, 'sg-raw-pipeline-ssm', !Select [ 7, !Split [ '-', !Ref AWS::StackId ] ] ] ]
      GroupDescription: Security group for pipeline EC2 access
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 10.0.0.0/16
          FromPort: 443
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 443
          Description: 'SSM access for EC2'
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: -1
          IpProtocol: -1
          ToPort: -1
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref Prefix, !Ref EnvironmentName, 'sg-raw-pipeline-ssm', !Select [ 7, !Split [ '-', !Ref AWS::StackId ] ] ] ]
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${VpcStackName}-VpcId"


  ##############################################################################
  #
  # INSTANCES
  #
  ##############################################################################

  PipelineInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAZs '' ]
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref PipelineEc2InstanceProfile
      InstanceType: !Ref EC2InstanceType
      ImageId: !Ref EC2ImageId
      KeyName: !Ref SSHKeyName
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt PipelineSecurityGroup.GroupId
      SubnetId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${VpcStackName}-PrivateSubnet4"
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref Prefix, !Ref EnvironmentName, 'ec2-raw-pipeline', !Select [ 7, !Split [ '-', !Ref AWS::StackId ] ] ] ]
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          cd /tmp
          sudo yum update -y
          sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
          sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
          sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent

  VpcEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      PrivateDnsEnabled: True
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt SsmSecurityGroup.GroupId
      ServiceName: !Sub "com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.ssm"
      SubnetIds:
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub "${VpcStackName}-PrivateSubnet4"
      VpcEndpointType: 'Interface'
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${VpcStackName}-VpcId"

################################################################################
#
# OUTPUTS
#
################################################################################

Outputs:

  PipelineEc2PrivateUrl:
    Description: Private DNS name of the newly created EC2 instance
    Value: !GetAtt [ PipelineInstance, PrivateDnsName ]

  PipelineEc2PrivateIp:
    Description: Private IP address of the newly created EC2 instance
    Value: !GetAtt [ PipelineInstance, PrivateIp ]
```